# How could I check if a field exists or not in a particular document when using firebase?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

In Firebase Firestore I Have a Collection and its corresponding document like

```
PRODUCTS
        Document with AutoId
                            Fields:
                                   a
                                   b
```

I want to check if the field exists or not in that document

```
Ex- if field a exists some code will execute if not exists some other code will execute
```

```
if(task.isSuccessful()){
   for(long x=0;x<(long)task.getResult().get("no_of_products");x++){
      if(task.getResult().get("productID_"+x)==null){
        continue;
      }else{
         //some code
       }
   }
}
```

is this the correct way to check if the field exists in a document or not ?

Comment: should I just write like this ?

if(task.getResult().get("product_ID")==null){
                                    continue;
                                }

Comment: do you want to check if a document exists or a key value par exists ?

Comment: I want to check if key value pair exists or not I don't need about document

Comment: the above for loop itself retrieving all the fields in that document

Comment: I think it would help to know which field you're talking about; do you mean Fields or 'a'/'b' etc? I think you mean you want to see if for example, field 'a' exists and if so, do one task and if not, do another. However, how you determine if it exists will depend on if you're reading in the data and checking it in code, or if you want to directly check in in Firestore. It may help even more to get a better idea what your actual Firestore structure looks like - can you include a screenshot of that?

Comment: I gone through firestore  guide and solved by retrieving the document snapshot and checking the field   as   task.getResult().contain("FieldName)  in the if condition. if the field doesn't exists I wrote continue keyword in the if condition for the next iteration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to retrieve documents where the field exists, no matter what value it has, you can use a `startAt` condition on your query:

```
db.collection("PRODUCTS")
  .orderBy("no_of_products")
  .startAt(null);
```

Comment: NO I cant understand you. what I meant is  Task<DocumentSnapshot> task   is the document  in which I'm using the field no_of_products so that I can iterate through that range.In the same document there are productID key value pairs, some of the key value pairs are missing so upon iterating that for loop I was retrieving the key value pair which doe's not exists. so I want to check that key value pair if exsits only I want to continue to next lines of code

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean there. Did you try the code I gave? It will return only documents that have a `no_of_products` field.

Comment: yeah it helped me.